# Different behavior of wcscpy in g++ and vc++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  wchar_t ws1[] = L"happylearning";
  wchar_t ws2[] = L"Happy";

  wcscpy(ws2, ws1);
  wcout << ws1 << endl
        << ws2 << endl;
}
```

This produces different output in VC++ and g++.

As: In VC++:

```
happylearning
happylearning
```

In g++:

```
rning
happylearning
```

Could anyone let me know why there is diffrence.

I have include all necessary header files

Comment: As stated in the documentation of [`wcscpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcscpy): "_The behavior is undefined if the dest array is not large enough._"

Comment: This output would make sense if g++ is placing `w2` on the stack in front of `w1` so that the buffer overflow of copying `ws1` into `ws2` would overwrite the contents of `w1`. VC++ is not doing that reversed ordering, so overflowing `ws2` is not overwriting `ws1`.

Answer (score 4):

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcscpy) for `wcscopy()`:

> The behavior is **undefined** if the dest array is not large enough.

*Undefined* means one compiler (like VC++) and another (like g++) are free to produce different behavior/results.

In `wchar_t ws1[]=L"happylearning";`, `ws1` is 14 characters long (13 + 1 null terminator), due to this way of initializing a *C-style array* of `char`. While in `wchar_t ws2[]=L"Happy";`, `ws2` is only 6 characters long (5 + 1 null terminator). So according to the excerpt from the documentation of `wcscpy()` stated here above, the *destination array* (`ws2`) is too small for `ws1` to be copied onto it. Hence a violation of this and thus the *undefined behavior* you encountered.

It's worth mentioning that this is not at all a consistent discrepancy between two given compilers, but that *undefined behavior* means that even for the same compiler the results are not guaranteed to reproduce or remain consistent in any form.